# Adding Objects to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I'm trying to have the user enter dates to store it but I can't seem to get it down.

```
public class Planner {
private int MaxEvents = 10;
private int numEvents=0;
OurDate a = new OurDate();
Event events []= new Event[MaxEvents];

public void enterDate(){
    OurDate date = new OurDate();
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Date: \nEnter day: ");
    int day=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter month: ");
    int month=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter year: ");
    int year=input.nextInt();
    date.setDay(day);
    date.setMonth(month);
    date.setYear(year);
    events[numEvents] = date;
    numEvents++;

}
```

The problem comes when I try to add the created object to the array.

Here is the other class for reference for setDay,setMonth,setYear:
    public class OurDate {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

```
public OurDate(int day, int month, int year){
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}
public OurDate() {
    this.day=1;
    this.month = 1;
    this.year = 2010;
}
public void setDay(int day) {
    if(day>=1 && day <=31){
        this.day = day;
    }else if(day>31){
        this.day = 1;
    }
}
public int getDay() {
    return day;
}
public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}
public void setMonth(int month) {
    if(month >=1 && month<=12)
        this.month = month;
}
public int getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}


}
```

Comment: Do you have the code for your OurDate class?

Comment: And your Event class :) ?

Comment: Yep just added it to the post above

Comment: it seems you are assigning OurDate object to array of Event class?

Comment: Well that was a stupid little mistake i did......assigned it to the wrong one...

Comment: By the way, no need to re-invent [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) in real work (rather than homework assignment).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add an object of type `OurDate` to the array `events` because the array expects objects of type `Event` as mentioned in its declaration:

```
Event events []= new Event[MaxEvents];
```

Based on the code from your `OurDate` class, it does not extend `Event`, so adding such an object into the array cannot be done.

You can alter your array to take OurDate objects like that:

```
OurDate[] dates = new OurDate[MaxEvents];
```

Or you can create a new `Event` object and set the `OurDate` object in it - something like this:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.setDate(date);
events[numEvents] = event;
```